# Как задать срок хранения ключа?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как задать срок хранения ключа? как предотвратить появление модального окна после закрытия а потом октрытия браузера?

```
if (localStorage.getItem("story") !== 'true') {

    localStorage.setItem("story", "true");

    // Calling the bootstrap modal


    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Modal").modal();
    }, 6000);

    $('.modal button').on('click', function(){
        $('.step-block').remove();
        $('.modal .modal-body').append(initPassInterview)
        $('.modal .share').on('click', function(){

             window.setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                }, 3000);
        })

    })
 }
```

Comment: Сделать объект с переменной и timestamp, преобразовать в json, записать в localStorage json массив. При открытии страницы разбирать json массив и сравнивать timestamp с текущим временем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Срок хранения нельзя указать для localStorage, пользователь и браузер сами определяют это. Можете использовать куки для этого, [вот](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) удобная либа.

```js
if (Cookies.get('story') !== 'true') {
    // 7 дней, 1/48 поставит на 30 мин, подробнее тут https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#expire-cookies-in-less-than-a-day
    Cookies.set('story', 'true', { expires: 7, path: '' }); 

    // Calling the bootstrap modal


    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Modal").modal();
    }, 6000);

    $('.modal button').on('click', function(){
        $('.step-block').remove();
        $('.modal .modal-body').append(initPassInterview)
        $('.modal .share').on('click', function(){

             window.setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                }, 3000);
        })

    })
 }
```

Удалить можно так: Cookies.remove('story');